# Updating assembly causes error

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

I updated a single 3rd party assembly, and I am getting an error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Some.Assembly, Version=1.0.3.15922, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=62a6874124340d6e' or one of its dependencies. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

When I updated this assembly, the version is now `1.0.3.23655`.

Is it because of a strong named assembly that other dependent assemblies are complaining about?

Answer (score 2):

It's the version.  You either need to rebuild (assuming that the dependent assemblies are yours), or if you are positive that the new version is compatible, you can configure .net to use the newer assembly.  Details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is what it is complaining about.

Comment: Well not exactly the versions are wrong, so even if the key is right it will still complain

Answer (score 0):

Please look [here](http://forums.asp.net/ThreadNavigation.aspx?PostID=2049698&NavType=Next) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/76f56b2c-d5aa-437f-a2ac-8993e5799a31) to guide you in resolving your versioning issue. Is your assembly signed using strongname?

Hope this helps.